# Formating Date in an angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

can some one tell me the way to format or to have a HTML date picker in the format ddmmyyyy. I am using HTML5 date input field, to the best of my knowledge it doesn't support the format i need, but i need to achieve.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have you tried so far? Your question could be improved by showing us that you've made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear. If you need to change the format of the data in the model you can use  [formatters and parsers](http://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html).

If what you want is to change how the datepicker formats the date in the GUI you are out of luck. This is all up to the browsers - and they all display the date-input in different ways. The datepickers are usually much better on mobile devices than on desktop-browsers.

I would suggest using a 3rd party datepicker, such as the [angular material datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) or [AngularUI Bootstrap Datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)